# What is the meaning of "kill yourself" in quran 2:54?

Tags: quran, prophet-musa

> Sahih International: And [recall] when Moses said to his people, "O my people, indeed you have wronged yourselves by your taking of the calf [for worship]. So repent to your Creator and **kill yourselves**. That is best for [all of] you in the sight of your Creator." Then He accepted your repentance; indeed, He is the Accepting of repentance, the Merciful.(2:54)

What is the meaning of "*and kill yourself*"?

Comment: The meaning is obvious. They should apply the punishment of apostasy on each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of **"kill"** is rather obvious, it means means taking life or causing death.

Most exegetes hold that it does not mean that every individual was commanded to kill himself, rather **"yourselves"** means "each other" similar to the usage of the expression in other places such as:

> #### ولا تلمزوا أنفسكم
>
> (lit.) And do not insult yourselves
>
> <sup>— [Quran 49:11](https://quran.com/49:11?font=v1&translations=20%2C17)</sup>

> #### فسلموا على أنفسكم
>
> (lit.)  greet yourselves
>
> <sup>— [Quran 24:61](https://quran.com/24:61?font=v1&translations=20%2C17)</sup>

So the meaning is that a group of the Bani Israel were commanded to execute another group as punishment for their apostasy, i.e. worship of the golden calf.

Comment: But Allah askes them to repent. Why will he ask people to repent and kill themselves

Comment: Why not? Killing is their punishment and a means of their repentance, one does not rule out the other. For example in our shariah a murderer, fornicator, thief etc. is punished even if he repents.

Comment: So people who were kill will enter heaven